# Spring @Autowire not working in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

For my university task I need to use various methods of injecting dependencies, I'm stuck on autowire using annotation, because it says that the dependency has not been initialized. My code:

```
class TeleporterDeliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var teleporter: Teleporter

    override fun deliver(pkg: Package): Int {
        teleporter.teleport(pkg)
        return 0
    }
}
```

Teleporter class:

```
class Teleporter3000 : Teleporter {
    override fun teleport(pkg: Package) {
        println("Teleporting package ${pkg.id}...")
    }
}
```

I also have this defined in xml:

```
<bean id="teleporterDeliveryMethod" class="app.delivery.TeleporterDeliveryMethod"/>
<bean id="teleporter" class="app.delivery.Teleporter3000" scope="prototype"/>
```

Teleporter is an interface with one method `teleport(...)`

When this code is run, the compiles says: `Exception in thread "main" kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property teleporter has not been initialized`

If I inject dependencies in xml manually, it works as expected:

```
class="app.delivery.TeleporterDeliveryMethod">
    <property name="teleporter" ref="teleporter"/>
</bean>
```

Even autowiring works in xml:

```
<bean id="teleporterDeliveryMethod" class="app.delivery.TeleporterDeliveryMethod" autowire="byType"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<context:component-scan base-package="app"/>`

was missing from bean declarations